# JavaScript: nested For Loops don't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, nested, nested-loops

So I have this task to write `isUniform()` function, which takes an array as an argument and returns true if all elements in the array are identical.

This is what I wrote:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

isUniform(array);
console.log("- - - - - ")
isUniform([1, 1, 1, 1]);

function isUniform(array) {
   var counter = 0;

   for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
      for (var j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
         if (array[i] !== array[j]) {
            counter++;
         }
      }
   }

   if (counter === 0) {
    return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

The thing is, it only prints out `- - - - -`. Why?

EDIT:
Okay, I thought when you return something, it automatically prints out. 
But there is another problem - why does it return true in the first example?

Alright, thank you for your tips. True, I didn't think of the efficiency. Changed to this:

```
function isUniform(array) {

   for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
       if (array[i] !== array[i+1]) {
           return false;
       }
   }

   return true;
}
```

Now it works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: `isUniform` doesn't print and you don't do anything with its result.

Comment: You have to `console.log(isUniform(array));`

Comment: "nested for loops" definitely work. 100%.

Comment: Just an aside - you couldnt have picked a more inefficient way to solve this. You check each element 2 times. You could have looped once, and checked the element next to it, and finished 1 early.

Comment: And what exactly do you expect it to output? You haven't even said what you are trying to do

Comment: My thinking was wrong, thank you for correcting it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to display the result of the function.

You could check just every element against the first one end exit early if not equal.

```js
function isUniform(array) {
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[0] !== array[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(isUniform([1, 2, 3, 4]));
console.log(isUniform([1, 1, 1, 1]));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use ES6 `Set` and check its size.

```js
const isUniform = arr => new Set(arr).size == 1;

console.log(isUniform([1, 1, 1, 1]))
console.log(isUniform([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: set knows size.

Comment: Im confused, what makes you think the OP is trying to output the result of the function?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been answered but you can also make use of `every` in the following way:

```js
function isUniform(arr){
    return arr.every(function(x){return x === arr[0]});
}

console.log(isUniform([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(isUniform([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]));
```

Comment: I haven't come to 'every' so far, but I will definitely look this up, thanks!